# Python (data visualization)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, visualization

How do I make matplotlib graph (figure 2) the same as seaborn (figure 1)? I want to remove the central grids.
I try to use `plt.gca().axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])`, but it also removes the label.

[image: 1]

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer since you haven't provided any code, but if `ax.grid()` is what you have written, change it to `ax.grid(axis'x')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If grid are already present in the plot, as in your figure 2, you can turn off horizontal grid line passing `b = False` and `axis = 'x'` to [`plt.grid()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html):

```
ax.grid(b = False, axis = 'x')
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
y = [10, 15, 11, 12, 8]

plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x = x, height = y, color = 'blue')
ax.grid(b = False, axis = 'x')

plt.show()
```

[image]